# Gravlax still red on skin side after 24h of curing

Tags: salmon, curing

I am trying to make gravlax (lox).

### Method

1. Clean off salmon fillet (~200g tail portion)
2. Mix 50/50 table salt and sugar
3. Coat skin side in salt/sugar mixture, rub in
4. Coat non-skin side in dill
5. Coat non-skin side in salt/sugar mixture, rub in
6. Place in covered container
7. Place in fridge for 18-24 hours

### Problem

After 24 hours, the thin parts are cured, but the skin side of the thick part is still red.

[image: gravlax still red on skin side]

### What I have tried

Cutting off the skin - completely effective, but makes it very tough, also all the videos I watched had it cured with the skin on, and those came out fine

Curing for longer - did not seem to have any effect

Rubbing salt/sugar mixture directly on end - this seemed to help a bit right on the end, but it was still red further in

Place weight on top - some videos I watched had the fillet wrapped in cling wrap and smooshed with a weight, but this did not seem to have any effect

[image: professional smooshing setup]

Comment: 18-24 hours seems rather short to me; I typically leave it in the fridge for 2-3 days. But you said that leaving it longer didn't help.
It is tricky to get the thicker and thinner parts to behave in the same way. What I try to do is to buy more uniform pieces of salmon. (I typically remove the skin first as well, but that shouldn't really matter.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, first, I don't think that gravlax looks that bad. Gravlax is never going to be the uniform peach/orange color that cold smoked salmon is (lox).  It just looks a little bit under-cured.

There are two things I do that are different from you, when I make Gravlax:

1. I cure it for a minimum of 72 hours, turning every 12 hours or so (and pressing the whole time, but that's a texture thing).
2. My cure includes a couple shots of aquavit.  I find that the alcohol helps the cure penetrate into the center of the salmon.

[Here's my recipe](http://fuzzychef.org/gravlax/).

Comment: I flipped it over and left for another 24 hours and it's looking much better. Thanks!